# xpath: select everything except one node and all its subnodes

Tags: xpath

I am looking for an xpath query, that selects the whole document but without the tags with an attribute off="true" and all their subnodes!

The first I know how to manage:

```
//*[not(@off='true')]
```

But it still selects the subnodes..

would be really nice if someone can help me out!

greetings!

Answer (score 1):

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*/@off = 'true')]
```